# Server stuck in INTERNAL DDL LOG RECOVERY IN PROGRESS

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.6

Recently, one of my servers had a crash. I had alot of trouble but managed to restore everything.

But,

Now, the first background thread upon startup is locked on "INTERNAL DDL LOG RECOVERY IN PROGRESS" and never stops. **It does not affect the system** as it does not consume any CPU / memory, it simply just starts and never stops.

Ive found many with the same problem but there is no solution for this problem.

I have run a `mysqlcheck` on all tables, and they are all OK.

All tables are of **Innodb**

Does anyone have any idea how I can solve this?

**Mysql version 5.6.13-log**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have MySQL 5.6.21 on my laptop running Windows 8.1 and it is doing nothing. It still has that state. Please keep in mind that this state exists in the `performance schema`, in the table `threads`, in the column `PROCESSLIST_INFO`.

Please note the [**MySQL Documentation on PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA.THREADS.PROCESSLIST_INFO**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/threads-table.html)

> The statement the thread is executing, or NULL if it is not executing any statement. The statement might be the one sent to the server, or an innermost statement if the statement executes other statements. For example, if a CALL statement executes a stored procedure that is executing a SELECT statement, the PROCESSLIST_INFO value shows the SELECT statement.

There is still an [**active bug report for MySQL 5.6.20, 5.6.22, 5.7.6 on this**](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=74517). The [performance schema is enabled by default in MySQL 5.6](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/performance-schema-system-variables.html#sysvar_performance_schema). Therefore, the only solution, at this time, would be to disable the performance schema. You would have look for future releases to see if this has been resolved.

Personally, I would not worry about this. It seems to behave like MySQL Replication's I/O and SQL threads. Those threads poll indefinitely. Log recovery of this nature would happen during MySQL startup and should not be polling after MySQL Startup and InnoDB Crash Recovery have completed. If the bug simply left the state unchanged and nothing is going on, you could go on using MySQL as usual.

To verify this, please do the following:

STEP 01 : Look in the error log and make sure

- crash recovery had finished
- `MySQL: ready for connections` appears near the bottom

STEP 02 : Log into MySQL, and run this

```
mysql> select * from information_schema.engines where engine='InnoDB'\G
```

It should look like this

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
      ENGINE: InnoDB
     SUPPORT: DEFAULT
     COMMENT: Supports transactions, row-level locking, and foreign keys
TRANSACTIONS: YES
          XA: YES
  SAVEPOINTS: YES
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Rolando, thank you very much for the great answer!